# Django x-www-form-urlencoded request

Tags: django

I'm trying to do the following request with django :
[image]

I tried the following code but it doesn't work :

```
data = {'username': admin, 
        'password': 123, 
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'client_id': 'xxxx',
        'client_secret': 'xxxx'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is form-encoded by default.

> Typically, you want to send some form-encoded data — much like an HTML
>   form. To do this, simply pass a dictionary to the data argument. Your
>   dictionary of data will automatically be form-encoded when the request
>   is made.

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
>>> print r.text
{
  "origin": "179.13.100.4",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "key2": "value2",
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post",
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "23",
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity, deflate, compress, gzip",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/0.8.0",
    "Host": "127.0.0.1:7077",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": ""
}
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/#make-a-post-request

Comment: Thanks it works great. So now the request is executed correctly but I have the following error after the execution of the request : {'error': 'unsupported_grant_type'}

Comment: According to what I read this error is returned if the data is not sent with the header {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}. But I sent the header with this request no ?